# How could I change my canvas color wheel so that its edges are smooth like the CSS version?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

How could I change my canvas so that it's smooth (I think it's called anti-aliased) like the CSS version?

[image]

```js
// https://codepen.io/private_akongkj/pen/RwRMzqY?editors=1010 came from https://codepen.io/bantic/pen/zNKopG?editors=0010 and https://medium.com/@bantic/hand-coding-a-color-wheel-with-canvas-78256c9d7d43

function xy2polar(x, y) {
  const r = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
  const phi = Math.atan2(y, x);
  return [r, phi];
}

// rad in [-π, π] range
// return degree in [0, 360] range
function rad2deg(rad) {
  return ((rad + Math.PI) / (2 * Math.PI)) * 360;
}

function createColorWheel(canvas) {
  console.log('createColorWheel(canvas)', canvas);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const radius = canvas.width / 2;
  const image = ctx.createImageData(2 * radius, 2 * radius);
  const data = image.data;

  for (let x = -radius; x < radius; x++) {
    for (let y = -radius; y < radius; y++) {
      const [r, phi] = xy2polar(x, y);

      if (r > radius) {
        // skip all (x,y) coordinates that are outside of the circle
        continue;
      }

      const deg = rad2deg(phi);

      // Figure out the starting index of this pixel in the image data array.
      const rowLength = 2 * radius;
      const adjustedX = x + radius; // convert x from [-50, 50] to [0, 100] (the coordinates of the image data array)
      const adjustedY = y + radius; // convert y from [-50, 50] to [0, 100] (the coordinates of the image data array)
      const pixelWidth = 4; // each pixel requires 4 slots in the data array
      const index = (adjustedX + adjustedY * rowLength) * pixelWidth;

      const hue = deg;
      const saturation = 1.0;
      const value = 1.0;

      const [red, green, blue] = hsv2rgb(hue, saturation, value);
      const alpha = 255;

      data[index] = red;
      data[index + 1] = green;
      data[index + 2] = blue;
      data[index + 3] = alpha;
    }
  }

  ctx.putImageData(image, 0, 0);
}

// hue in range [0, 360]
// saturation, value in range [0,1]
// return [r,g,b] each in range [0,255]
// See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSV
function hsv2rgb(hue, saturation, value) {
  const chroma = value * saturation;
  const hue1 = hue / 60;
  const x = chroma * (1 - Math.abs((hue1 % 2) - 1));
  let r1, g1, b1;
  if (hue1 >= 0 && hue1 <= 1) {
    [r1, g1, b1] = [chroma, x, 0];
  } else if (hue1 >= 1 && hue1 <= 2) {
    [r1, g1, b1] = [x, chroma, 0];
  } else if (hue1 >= 2 && hue1 <= 3) {
    [r1, g1, b1] = [0, chroma, x];
  } else if (hue1 >= 3 && hue1 <= 4) {
    [r1, g1, b1] = [0, x, chroma];
  } else if (hue1 >= 4 && hue1 <= 5) {
    [r1, g1, b1] = [x, 0, chroma];
  } else if (hue1 >= 5 && hue1 <= 6) {
    [r1, g1, b1] = [chroma, 0, x];
  }

  const m = value - chroma;
  const [r, g, b] = [r1 + m, g1 + m, b1 + m];

  // Change r,g,b values from [0,1] to [0,255]
  return [255 * r, 255 * g, 255 * b];
}

createColorWheel(document.getElementById('canvas'));
```

```css
#wheel {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: conic-gradient(rgb(255, 0, 0), rgb(255, 255, 0), rgb(0, 255, 0), rgb(0, 255, 255), rgb(0, 0, 255), rgb(255, 0, 255), rgb(255, 0, 0));
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wheel"></div><canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Composite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) your aliased circle with an anti-aliased one:

```js
// https://codepen.io/private_akongkj/pen/RwRMzqY?editors=1010 came from https://codepen.io/bantic/pen/zNKopG?editors=0010 and https://medium.com/@bantic/hand-coding-a-color-wheel-with-canvas-78256c9d7d43

function xy2polar(x, y) {
  const r = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
  const phi = Math.atan2(y, x);
  return [r, phi];
}

// rad in [-π, π] range
// return degree in [0, 360] range
function rad2deg(rad) {
  return ((rad + Math.PI) / (2 * Math.PI)) * 360;
}

function createColorWheel(canvas) {
  console.log('createColorWheel(canvas)', canvas);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const radius = canvas.width / 2;
  const image = ctx.createImageData(2 * radius, 2 * radius);
  const data = image.data;

  for (let x = -radius; x < radius; x++) {
    for (let y = -radius; y < radius; y++) {
      const [r, phi] = xy2polar(x, y);

      if (r > radius) {
        // skip all (x,y) coordinates that are outside of the circle
        continue;
      }

      const deg = rad2deg(phi);

      // Figure out the starting index of this pixel in the image data array.
      const rowLength = 2 * radius;
      const adjustedX = x + radius; // convert x from [-50, 50] to [0, 100] (the coordinates of the image data array)
      const adjustedY = y + radius; // convert y from [-50, 50] to [0, 100] (the coordinates of the image data array)
      const pixelWidth = 4; // each pixel requires 4 slots in the data array
      const index = (adjustedX + adjustedY * rowLength) * pixelWidth;

      const hue = deg;
      const saturation = 1.0;
      const value = 1.0;

      const [red, green, blue] = hsv2rgb(hue, saturation, value);
      const alpha = 255;

      data[index] = red;
      data[index + 1] = green;
      data[index + 2] = blue;
      data[index + 3] = alpha;
    }
  }

  ctx.putImageData(image, 0, 0);
  // apply antialias
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(radius+0.5, radius+0.5, radius-0.5, 0, Math.PI*2);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
  ctx.fill();
  // revert to defaults
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
}

// hue in range [0, 360]
// saturation, value in range [0,1]
// return [r,g,b] each in range [0,255]
// See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSV
function hsv2rgb(hue, saturation, value) {
  const chroma = value * saturation;
  const hue1 = hue / 60;
  const x = chroma * (1 - Math.abs((hue1 % 2) - 1));
  let r1, g1, b1;
  if (hue1 >= 0 && hue1 <= 1) {
    [r1, g1, b1] = [chroma, x, 0];
  } else if (hue1 >= 1 && hue1 <= 2) {
    [r1, g1, b1] = [x, chroma, 0];
  } else if (hue1 >= 2 && hue1 <= 3) {
    [r1, g1, b1] = [0, chroma, x];
  } else if (hue1 >= 3 && hue1 <= 4) {
    [r1, g1, b1] = [0, x, chroma];
  } else if (hue1 >= 4 && hue1 <= 5) {
    [r1, g1, b1] = [x, 0, chroma];
  } else if (hue1 >= 5 && hue1 <= 6) {
    [r1, g1, b1] = [chroma, 0, x];
  }

  const m = value - chroma;
  const [r, g, b] = [r1 + m, g1 + m, b1 + m];

  // Change r,g,b values from [0,1] to [0,255]
  return [255 * r, 255 * g, 255 * b];
}

createColorWheel(document.getElementById('canvas'));
```

```css
#wheel {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: conic-gradient(rgb(255, 0, 0), rgb(255, 255, 0), rgb(0, 255, 0), rgb(0, 255, 255), rgb(0, 0, 255), rgb(255, 0, 255), rgb(255, 0, 0));
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wheel"></div><canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: Wow! That's amazing! I really appreciate it. Any chance you could comment on what those few lines are doing and how it transformed my output into the desired result? Thanks!